# C++ + glut + OpenGL + gluSphere doesn't draw anything

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, quadratic

I'm using GLUT to work with OpenGL (would work with SDL if I could). And I need to draw sphere. I'm using `gluSphere` but it simply doesn't draw anything.

Here's my GLUT initialization:

```cpp
// Initializes display
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
glutInitWindowSize(600, 600);

// Window settings
glutCreateWindow("Collision detect");
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Quadratic initialization:

```cpp
quadratic = gluNewQuadric();
if( !quadratic){
    throw new PROGRAM_EXCEPTION( "Cannot initialize quadartic", NULL);
}
gluQuadricNormals(quadratic, GLU_SMOOTH);
//gluQuadricDrawStyle( quadratic, GLU_FILL);
gluQuadricTexture(quadratic, GL_TRUE); // Tried both GL_TRUE and GL_FALSE
```

And my draw function:

```cpp
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef( position.getX(), position.getY(), position.getZ());
// This commented piece of code draws dot where I want it to,
// so coordinates and camera position are just fine
//  glBegin(GL_POINTS);
//  glVertex3f( 0,0,0);
//  glEnd();
gluSphere( quadratic, 20.0f, 32, 32); // Tried r = 0.02f, 0.2f, 2.0f, 20.0f, none works
glPopMatrix();
```

**Question:** what am I missing? Is there some trick in glut to enable quadratics to draw? Is it incompatible with some of my settings?

*I've spent several hours trying to sort this out, tried different things... If you need some other piece of code, just say which... I don't want to paste 2000 lines here. And one more thing, I've triple check, I'm not using it inside `glBegin()` and `glEnd()`. I have few triangles enclosing the space and they draw just fine.*

Comment: You shouldn't use `new` throwing an exception; think about what would happen if the `new` failed.

Comment: @datenwolf Ha ha! Thanks. I've seen throwing exceptions with `new Exception` when I was learning C++, well, long time ago and though that it's required syntax since than.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I have class that was taking care of drawing ball (called Sprit) it created quadratic in constructor (also copy constructor created it own quadratic) and deleted quadratic in destructor. Though I've written copy constructor carefully I forgot to write assign operator and I've used deleted quadratic. I was using glGetError() to check that everything's fine, no error was reported so I assumed it's problem of GLUT.

Answer (score 0):

> Question: what am I missing?

How about setting up a viewport and projection?

Comment: Oh, I've got `resize` function which takes care of that... Normal triangles works just fine.

Comment: What should I do when I find answer to my question myself? :)

Comment: @Vyktor: Write an answer and accept it (you won't get point for self-answer-acceptance).

Answer (score -1):

Use this guide http://www.mediafire.com/?x6h3hz6hn1wqq73

Chapter 2 mainly covers everything you are looking for. It also deals with the language and technology stacks you are using.

Comment: Perhaps helpful to the OP, but this does not really answer the question at hand, does it?

Comment: Fair enough, thought it would considering it runs through entire topic at hand (generating a 3d sphere) but that's something for me to remember. Apologies. Cheers.